# How do I start an app when the system (Ubuntu) starts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have an app which I want to start when the server starts. I also want the app to automatically restart if it ever crashed and stops. My understanding is that I need to setup a systemd service for this. This is what I have done so far:

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/userapp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=User App
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/user
ExecStart=/home/user/start.sh
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=what
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting UserApp" | logger
./userapp
```

The problem is the service starts, no errors, then the service immediately stops, and the app. The start.sh and userapp are both chmod +x 755

Can anyone help me understand whats wrong?